# Android : Java/Kotlin Calendar special appear

Tags: java, android, calendar, kotlin

I work in Calendar appears in ListView
I have a refrence class for elements

```
internal class MyItem {
var name: String? = null
var number: String? = null
var nameDay:String? = null
```

}

In MainActivity i make ArrayList to save elements and get instance from calendar

```
private var arrayList: ArrayList<MyItem>? = null
private var cal:Calendar= Calendar.getInstance()
```

and function call from onCreate to filled ArrayList like this

```
private fun loaddata() {
```

varible brings us exactly the number of days of the month

```
var maxDays:Int = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

varible brings us a complete date

```
var today:Int = cal.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

some of FormatSimpleDate

```
var sdfDay:SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd")
var sdfNamDay:SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("E")
var sdfMonth:SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM")
```

then i make loop for 45 days

```
for( i in 0.. 45){
        val myItem = MyItem()

        myItem.name = sdfMonth.format(cal.time)
        myItem.number = sdfDay.format(cal.time)
        myItem.nameDay = sdfNamDay.format(cal.time)
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1)
        arrayList!!.add(myItem)
    }
```

The out put similar that

```
AUG Wed 30 / AUG Thu 31 / Sep Fri 01 / Sep Sat 02 / ... / Sep Sat 30 / Oct Sun 01 / Oct Mon 02 / etc
```

the function works perfectly without any error
But i want to appears to me on the first row month-day
in second row start to show just day until month change
if month change to next 
show in row month and day 
in next row show day only
Like this

```
AUG Wed 30 / Thu 31 / Sep Fri 01 / Sat 02 / ... / Sat 30 / Oct Sun 01 / Mon 02 / etc
```

i make more than one if statement
but not make good

Can any body help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need it anymore, but here you go with the code a little bit more kotliny/functional:

I replaced all the vars with vals and got rid of all null assignments. The crucial function you needed is the groupBy call on the list of items.

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

data class Item(
        val month: String,
        val number: String,
        val nameDay: String
) {
    val printDay = "$nameDay $number"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val maxDays: Int = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val sdfDay: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd")
    val sdfNamDay: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("E")
    val sdfMonth: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM")

    val items = (0..45).map {
        val item = Item(
                sdfMonth.format(cal.time),
                sdfDay.format(cal.time),
                sdfNamDay.format(cal.time)
        )
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        item
    }.groupBy {
        it.month
    }.entries.fold("", { acc, item ->
        acc + item.key + ": " + item.value.map { it.printDay }.joinToString(" / ") + "\n"
    })

    println(items)
}
```